# Laravel: How to send duplicate input name to update() in controller

Tags: php, laravel

**i want to update setting form of cms in laravel.**


**Problem:** my column is only **option_name** and **value**

**How to resolve problem input names for store data?**

**using array for input name?**

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKMgj.png)

**Migration:**

```
Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('option_name');
    $table->longText('value');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**setting.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('setting.update', [ 'settings' => $value]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <input name="value" value="{{ $settings->find(1)->value }}" type="text">
    @error('value') <p class="customized-errors">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    
    <input name="value" value="{{ $settings->find(2)->value }}" type="text">
    @error('value') <p class="customized-errors">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    
    <input name="value" value="{{ $settings->find(6)->value }}" type="text">
    @error('value') <p class="customized-errors">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
    
    <input  name="value" {{ (($settings->find(3)->value) == 1)? 'checked' : '' }} type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-primary" id="checkbox2">
    <label class="col-10 col-form-label text-label lable-customized text-cu"> کاربران می توانند نام نویسی کنند </label>
    
    <input name="value" {{ (($settings->find(4)->value) == 1)? 'checked' : '' }} checked type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-primary" id="checkbox2">
    <label class="col-10 col-form-label text-label lable-customized text-cu"> کاربران می توانند دیدگاه های خود را ثبت کنند </label>
    
    <input name="value" {{ (($settings->find(5)->value) == 1)? 'checked' : '' }} type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-primary" id="checkbox2">
    <label class="col-10 col-form-label text-label lable-customized text-cu"> دیدگاه ها به صورت خودکار تایید شوند </label>
    
    
    <input name="value" {{ (($settings->find(7)->value) == 1)? 'checked' : '' }} type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-primary" id="checkbox2">
    <label class="col-10 col-form-label text-label lable-customized text-cu">  از موتورهای جستجو درخواست کن تا محتوای سایت را بررسی نکنند</label>
    
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sl-xs">save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Change the `name="value"` to whatever the name of the column is. In your code, which value does the controller work with? Each of them overwrites the previous one.

Comment: how to set name to array values?
value['title'] not work

Comment: `name="title"` etc
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your all input into dynamic input as `name=value[]` 
Now in controller `dd($request->value)`, you will get this input name as an **array**, like :

```
[value] => Array
(
    [1] => value 1
    [2] => value 2
    [3] => value 3
    [4] => value 4
    [5] => value 5
    [6] => value 6
    [7] => value 7
)
```

I think you dont need dynamic input, in this case you just need to change your `name` attribute as `name="site_name"`,  `name="site_description"`, `name="can_register"`, `name="can_comment"`, `name="auto_accept_comment"`, `name="can_post_page"`, `name="can_index"`.

Comment: tanks. i used name="site_name" and ...
this is better.